# Imitate OpenCL float2 type in C++

Tags: c++, opencl

In OpenCL C99 we can write this to create a new instance of 'float2' :

`float f = (float2)(1.f, 2.f);`

My problem is that I need to use the EXACT SAME code in C++, for this I have create
a new class float2, but it seems that the following operator is not called in this case :

`inline float2 operator()(const float a, const float b) { return float2(a, b); }`

Does someone has an idea for a solution ?

Comment: You won't be able to use that exact syntax to initialise your class/struct in C++, since it has a different meaning. If you just need to use the same code from OpenCL C and C++, are you able to change the OpenCL C version as well? For example, you could define some macro that performs the appropriate initialisation for each, and then the code would be identical.

Comment: There is a complex number template on the standard library. Use it. For answerers: Provide standard solutions, not custom structs combined with comma operator tricks please

Comment: Just for the case, note the initialization of complex could be something like float2 f = float2(1.0f,2.0f); (If you alias std::complex<float> to float2), which is pretty similar to your requested syntax

Comment: I have tested it and you could use enclosing parens (Its a parametrized C style casting), so your exact syntax could be emulated on this way

Answer (score 1):

Following on from [jprice's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909389/immitate-opencl-constructor#comment36817157_23909389), if you can change the syntax of your OpenCL code, you could make this work in both languages by defining a simple `struct` in your C++ code:

```
struct float2 {
  float x, y;
  // define operators here
};
```

then instead of using the "cast-style" syntax above, you could do:

```
float2 f;
f.x = 1.f; f.y = 2.f;
```

which would work in both.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. The line `float2 f = (float2)(1.f, 2.f);` can be interpreted in two ways:

1. If `float2` is a type, cast the result of `(1.f, 2.f)` (an expression using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), returning a `float`) to a `float2`. Since there is no cast from `float` to `float2`, this fails.
2. If `float2` is a function/functor, execute `func2` using the provided two arguments.

Using the former interpretation, we could try to add the conversion operator like you tried, which would have to be a conversion from `float` to `float2`, since the result of `(1.f, 2.f)` is a `float` (2.f). We would not have access to the first argument in this conversion though (which is lost after the comma operator), so this wouldn't get us anywhere.

Using the latter interpretation, we can write something along the lines of:

```
detail::float2 float2(float x, float y)
{
    detail::float2 result(x, y);
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    detail::float2 f = (float2)(1.f, 2.f);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I've put the `float2` struct (omitted for brevity) in a namespace called `detail`, which was necessary in order to resolve the ambiguity caused by having both a type and a function named `float2` in the same namespace. Sadly, I don't think there is a way around this and it is the closest we can get. You won't be able to use the exact same code in OpenCL and C++ though.

Answer (score 0):

The Standard Library contains a header `<complex>`, which defines a template `std::complex` dessigned to do arithmetic computations with complex numbers.
That complex numbers are represented as pairs of floating-point values (The real part and the imaginary part), so it could be used to emulate your `float2` type.

If you define an alias `float2` you could emulate **your exact syntax** via C style casting:

```
#include <complex>

typedef std::complex<float> float2;

int main()
{
    float2 f = (float2)(1.0,2.0);
}
```

As you can see, you can emulate that syntax using standard C++ facilities only, not custom tricks.

[Here](http://ideone.com/QDT2wr) is a running example.

Comment: The output on your example is `(2,0)`, which makes sense, as `(1.0,2.0)` is going to evaluate to `2.0`, which will be treated like a complex number with no imaginary part.